# Filter on column values of which first two characters are uppercase

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, filtering, uppercase

I'm trying to filter a table using Pyspark in which all the two first characters of all values of one of the column start with two uppercase letters such as 'UTrecht', 'NEw York', etc

This is what I've tried but this utterly failed:

```
df_filtered=df.filter(F.col("column_name").isUpper())
```

I've also tried:

```
df_filtered=df.filter(str.isupper,"affiliation_city")
```

which resulted in the following error:

> filter() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I'm a relative newbie to Pyspark so any advise would be appreciated.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if the substr is upper using substr function and upper function as below

You take the first two letters with `substr` and compare the with uppercase version if this substring with `upper(F.col("test").substr(1, 2))` and filter them as

```
df.filter(
   F.col("test").substr(1, 2) == F.upper(F.col("test").substr(1, 2))
).show()
```

If you want more flexibility,(but its not the best way to to i) you can have a udf that returns True/False with python isupper() function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType


upp  = udf(lambda x: x[0:2].isupper() if x!= None else False,BooleanType())

df.filter(upp('affiliation_city')).show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be getting me in the right direction. However, I still get a different TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: ` df.filter(df.affiliation_city.substr(1, 2).isUpper())` does this work?

Comment: Not quite as I still get TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable. I tried a workaround by creating an addition column using df=df.withColumn('2CHAR',F.col('affiliation_city').substr(1, 2)) and then trying to filter it using df=df.filter(col('2CHAR').isUpper()). But also this results in TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: It should be `isupper` and not `isUpper`, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: It seems like no function like isupper(isUpper) available in pyspark, I have updated the answer

Comment: Updated the answer again, you can use substr and compare it with same substr converted to upper.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. The function seems to work fine so that's good. But when I try to display or show the data, it throws the "
PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'"

Comment: Okay, you had None in the columns, updated the udf thing as well

Comment: Both solutions work for me. This was very learning. Thanks a bunch!!